# Eslint and Prettier no semi rule causes line execution when next line is wrapped in parens

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

I currently have the `nosemi` rule set in Prettier and ESLint. Consider the following.

```
let a = myArr.find(x => x.id === c.id)
let b = myArr2.find(x => x.id === c.id)

(a.id && a.id != b.id) && doStuff()
```

It tries to execute it as a function like so...

```
let b = myArr2.find(x => x.id === c.id)(a.id && a.id != b.id) && doStuff()
```

I could simply remove the parens but there are situations where I need parens for the next line to work properly.

I could also do something like `if (a.id && a.id != b.id) doStuff()` but at that point I am changing my code for style.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the standard semicolon as separator `;`.

```js
let a = [true].find(Boolean)

; (a || !a) && console.log('gotcha')
```

Or an empty block statement `{}`.

```js
let a = [true].find(Boolean)

{}

(a || !a) && console.log('gotcha')
```

Or use the [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void), which separates the lines, but that need a parenthesis to execute the second part.

```js
let a = [true].find(Boolean)

void ((a || !a) && console.log('gotcha'))
console.log(a);
```